# How to extend Laravel core class MessageBags

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to extend *Illuminate\Support\MessageBag* because of add some help methods but **I cant bind** my own class App\Support\MyMessageBag to laravel use my class (that extends App\Support\MyMessageBag) instead of original core class.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your code, when you want to use your new helper classes, are you sure to make the right `use` ?

Comment: I want to simplify printing error class in form fields. No I have to do some IF statement {!! ($errors->has('platform')) ? '<span class="error_text">' . $errors->first('platform') . '</span>' : '' !!} Instead of this I want to move IF logic to method class that extends MessageBags. I want to call for example $errors->errorClass('platform') and logic will bi insite this method.